# How to create layers with cytoscape concentric layout

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I tried to create a inner and outer layer with the concentric layout.
But I don't get it to work.

This is how it looks for me:

The inner and outer nodes get mixed up.

[image: current graph]

And this is what I have expected:

[image: expected]

My data:

```
{
 data: [
  {data: {
    id: 'innerA', level: 1 },
    group: 'nodes'
  },
  ....
  {data: {
    id: 'outA', level: 2 },
    group: 'nodes'
   },
  ....
  {
    data: { source: 'innerA', target: 'outA' },
    group: 'edges',
  },
  ....
  ],
}
```

And my layout

```
layout: {
  concentric: function( node ){
    return node.data("level");
  },
  levelWidth: function( ){
    return 2;
  },
  name: 'concentric',
  minNodeSpacing: 50,
  }
}
```

From what I have expected the concentric function in the layout, would assign the nodes
depending on the layer attribute in the node.

Hope someone has an idea.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: where is the doc about 'minNodeSpacing'? i can't find documented details about layouts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, layout places higher level nodes towards the center, therefore your inner nodes should have level 2, while outer ones should have level 1. Secondly, I don't know how levelWidth option works, but using default value instead of 2 works.

```js
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),

  style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      css: {
        'content': 'data(id)'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'edge',
      css: {
        'curve-style': 'straight',
      }
    }
  ],
  elements: [
  {data: {
    id: 'innerA', level: 2 },
    group: 'nodes'
  },
  {data: {
    id: 'innerB', level: 2 },
    group: 'nodes'
  },
  {data: {
    id: 'innerC', level: 2 },
    group: 'nodes'
  },
  {data: {
    id: 'innerD', level: 2 },
    group: 'nodes'
  },  
  {data: {
    id: 'outA', level: 1 },
    group: 'nodes'
   },
  {data: {
    id: 'outB', level: 1 },
    group: 'nodes'
   },
  {data: {
    id: 'outC', level: 1 },
    group: 'nodes'
   },
  {data: {
    id: 'outD', level: 1 },
    group: 'nodes'
   },
  {data: {
    id: 'outE', level: 1 },
    group: 'nodes'
   },
  {data: {
    id: 'outF', level: 1 },
    group: 'nodes'
   },
  {data: {
    id: 'outG', level: 1 },
    group: 'nodes'
   },
  {data: {
    id: 'outH', level: 1 },
    group: 'nodes'
   },   
  {
    data: { source: 'innerA', target: 'outA' },
    group: 'edges',
  },
  {
    data: { source: 'innerB', target: 'outC' },
    group: 'edges',
  },
  {
    data: { source: 'innerC', target: 'outE' },
    group: 'edges',
  },
  {
    data: { source: 'innerD', target: 'outG' },
    group: 'edges',
  },  
  ],
  layout: {
    name: 'concentric',
    concentric: function( node ){
      return node.data("level");
    },
    minNodeSpacing: 50
  }  
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 95%;
  width: 95%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.10.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much, you are absolutely right. I had my levels in the wrong order and I had to remove the levelWidth. And I myself found another error in my code. I create the graphs on a express server and cytoscape is used inside and angular app to display the graph. For some reason the concentric function in the layout went missing, inside my http request from the angular app to get the graph from the server. but now its all fine :)